# Change global font size in bookdown bs4 HTML book?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, bslib

I have created a `bs4` theme bookdown book. However, I am having no luck changing the global font size to be smaller.

In the `_output.yml` file, I have added the following `bslib` options: `font_scale` and `font-size-base`, but neither had any effect on the font size.

#### Attempt #1

```
bookdown::bs4_book:
  css: bs4_style.css
  theme:
    primary: "#4C566A"
    font_scale: 0.6
```

#### Attempt #2

```
bookdown::bs4_book:
  css: bs4_style.css
  theme:
    primary: "#4C566A"
    font-size-base: "0.5rem"
```

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to set `font_scale`, but it seems not working. My solution is to add a CSS fragment in the header of html.

The CSS code is saved into a file `css.html` with the following content:

```
<style>
#content {
    font-size: 0.95rem;
}
</style>
```

Then in `.output.yml`, the CSS fragment can be added to header by:

```
bookdown::bs4_book:
  .. other settings ..
  includes:
    in_header: [css.html]
```